# Display won't turn off with inactivity

Tags: power-management, xfce, lightdm, xfce4-power-manager

I am using `Ubuntu Studio 18.04.4 TLS` on a desktop tower and the display won't turn off when system is inactive. In fact, if I trigger the "screen off event" with `sh -c "sleep 1 && xset dpms force off"` the following happens :

- nothing. It's the same if I wait the setted time in
  Xfce-power-manager
- as soon as I move the mouse or hit a keyboard
  key, the screen goes black for 2 seconds then back to normal.

I tried to run xfce-power-manager in debug but nothing special seems to come out from the logs :

```
$ xfce4-power-manager --debug --no-daemon

** (xfce4-power-manager:2770): WARNING **: 18:58:39.574: Failed to get name owner: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NameHasNoOwner: Could not get owner of name 'org.freedesktop.PowerManagement': no such name


** (xfce4-power-manager:2770): WARNING **: 18:58:39.574: Failed to get name owner: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NameHasNoOwner: Could not get owner of name 'org.xfce.PowerManager': no such name

TRACE[xfpm-main.c:205] xfpm_start(): Starting the power manager
TRACE[xfpm-xfconf.c:642] xfpm_xfconf_init(): lock screen FALSE
TRACE[xfpm-xfconf.c:165] xfpm_xfconf_load(): Using default configuration for critical-power-level
TRACE[xfpm-xfconf.c:165] xfpm_xfconf_load(): Using default configuration for show-brightness-popup
TRACE[xfpm-xfconf.c:165] xfpm_xfconf_load(): Using default configuration for handle-brightness-keys
TRACE[xfpm-xfconf.c:165] xfpm_xfconf_load(): Using default configuration for show-tray-icon
TRACE[xfpm-xfconf.c:165] xfpm_xfconf_load(): Using default configuration for critical-power-action
TRACE[xfpm-xfconf.c:165] xfpm_xfconf_load(): Using default configuration for hibernate-button-action
TRACE[xfpm-xfconf.c:165] xfpm_xfconf_load(): Using default configuration for sleep-button-action
TRACE[xfpm-xfconf.c:165] xfpm_xfconf_load(): Using default configuration for lid-action-on-ac
TRACE[xfpm-xfconf.c:165] xfpm_xfconf_load(): Using default configuration for lid-action-on-battery
TRACE[xfpm-xfconf.c:165] xfpm_xfconf_load(): Using default configuration for brightness-level-on-ac
TRACE[xfpm-xfconf.c:165] xfpm_xfconf_load(): Using default configuration for brightness-level-on-battery
TRACE[xfpm-xfconf.c:165] xfpm_xfconf_load(): Using default configuration for brightness-slider-min-level
TRACE[xfpm-xfconf.c:165] xfpm_xfconf_load(): Using default configuration for dpms-sleep-mode
TRACE[xfpm-xfconf.c:165] xfpm_xfconf_load(): Using default configuration for inactivity-on-ac
TRACE[xfpm-xfconf.c:165] xfpm_xfconf_load(): Using default configuration for inactivity-on-battery
TRACE[xfpm-xfconf.c:165] xfpm_xfconf_load(): Using default configuration for inactivity-sleep-mode-on-ac
TRACE[xfpm-xfconf.c:165] xfpm_xfconf_load(): Using default configuration for inactivity-sleep-mode-on-battery
TRACE[xfpm-xfconf.c:165] xfpm_xfconf_load(): Using default configuration for brightness-on-ac
TRACE[xfpm-xfconf.c:165] xfpm_xfconf_load(): Using default configuration for brightness-on-battery
TRACE[xfpm-xfconf.c:165] xfpm_xfconf_load(): Using default configuration for network-manager-sleep
TRACE[xfpm-xfconf.c:165] xfpm_xfconf_load(): Using default configuration for logind-handle-power-key
TRACE[xfpm-xfconf.c:165] xfpm_xfconf_load(): Using default configuration for logind-handle-suspend-key
TRACE[xfpm-xfconf.c:165] xfpm_xfconf_load(): Using default configuration for logind-handle-hibernate-key
TRACE[xfpm-xfconf.c:165] xfpm_xfconf_load(): Using default configuration for heartbeat-command

(xfce4-power-manager:2770): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: 18:58:39.583: ../../../../gobject/gsignal.c:2523: signal 'Changed' is invalid for instance '0x556d00ba3270' of type 'GDBusProxy'
TRACE[xfpm-polkit.c:287] xfpm_polkit_init_data(): Using unix session polkit subject
TRACE[xfpm-polkit.c:345] xfpm_polkit_check_auth_intern(): polkit request: (('unix-process', {'pid': <uint32 2770>, 'start-time': <uint64 208504>}), 'org.freedesktop.login1.power-off', @a{ss} {}, uint32 0, '')
TRACE[xfpm-polkit.c:366] xfpm_polkit_check_auth_intern(): Action=org.freedesktop.login1.power-off is authorized=TRUE
TRACE[xfpm-polkit.c:345] xfpm_polkit_check_auth_intern(): polkit request: (('unix-process', {'pid': <uint32 2770>, 'start-time': <uint64 208504>}), 'org.freedesktop.login1.reboot', @a{ss} {}, uint32 0, '')
TRACE[xfpm-polkit.c:366] xfpm_polkit_check_auth_intern(): Action=org.freedesktop.login1.reboot is authorized=TRUE
TRACE[xfpm-polkit.c:345] xfpm_polkit_check_auth_intern(): polkit request: (('unix-process', {'pid': <uint32 2770>, 'start-time': <uint64 208504>}), 'org.freedesktop.login1.suspend', @a{ss} {}, uint32 0, '')
TRACE[xfpm-polkit.c:366] xfpm_polkit_check_auth_intern(): Action=org.freedesktop.login1.suspend is authorized=TRUE
TRACE[xfpm-polkit.c:345] xfpm_polkit_check_auth_intern(): polkit request: (('unix-process', {'pid': <uint32 2770>, 'start-time': <uint64 208504>}), 'org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate', @a{ss} {}, uint32 0, '')
TRACE[xfpm-polkit.c:366] xfpm_polkit_check_auth_intern(): Action=org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate is authorized=FALSE
TRACE[xfpm-power.c:213] xfpm_power_check_polkit_auth(): using logind suspend backend
TRACE[xfpm-polkit.c:345] xfpm_polkit_check_auth_intern(): polkit request: (('unix-process', {'pid': <uint32 2770>, 'start-time': <uint64 208504>}), 'org.freedesktop.login1.suspend', @a{ss} {}, uint32 0, '')
TRACE[xfpm-polkit.c:366] xfpm_polkit_check_auth_intern(): Action=org.freedesktop.login1.suspend is authorized=TRUE
TRACE[xfpm-polkit.c:345] xfpm_polkit_check_auth_intern(): polkit request: (('unix-process', {'pid': <uint32 2770>, 'start-time': <uint64 208504>}), 'org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate', @a{ss} {}, uint32 0, '')
TRACE[xfpm-polkit.c:366] xfpm_polkit_check_auth_intern(): Action=org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate is authorized=FALSE
TRACE[xfpm-power.c:1446] xfpm_update_blank_time(): Timeout: 10
TRACE[xfpm-power.c:1446] xfpm_update_blank_time(): Timeout: 10
TRACE[xfpm-power.c:1446] xfpm_update_blank_time(): Timeout: 10
TRACE[xfpm-power.c:1446] xfpm_update_blank_time(): Timeout: 7
TRACE[xfpm-button.c:183] xfpm_button_xevent_key(): Grabbed key 124 : ((XfpmButtonKey) BUTTON_POWER_OFF)

(xfce4-power-manager:2770): xfce4-power-manager-WARNING **: 18:58:39.595: could not map keysym 1008ffa8 to keycode

TRACE[xfpm-button.c:183] xfpm_button_xevent_key(): Grabbed key 213 : ((XfpmButtonKey) BUTTON_HIBERNATE)
TRACE[xfpm-button.c:183] xfpm_button_xevent_key(): Grabbed key 150 : ((XfpmButtonKey) BUTTON_SLEEP)
TRACE[xfpm-button.c:183] xfpm_button_xevent_key(): Grabbed key 233 : ((XfpmButtonKey) BUTTON_MON_BRIGHTNESS_UP)
TRACE[xfpm-button.c:183] xfpm_button_xevent_key(): Grabbed key 232 : ((XfpmButtonKey) BUTTON_MON_BRIGHTNESS_DOWN)
TRACE[xfpm-button.c:183] xfpm_button_xevent_key(): Grabbed key 244 : ((XfpmButtonKey) BUTTON_BATTERY)
TRACE[xfpm-button.c:183] xfpm_button_xevent_key(): Grabbed key 238 : ((XfpmButtonKey) BUTTON_KBD_BRIGHTNESS_UP)
TRACE[xfpm-button.c:183] xfpm_button_xevent_key(): Grabbed key 237 : ((XfpmButtonKey) BUTTON_KBD_BRIGHTNESS_DOWN)
TRACE[xfpm-manager.c:645] xfpm_manager_inhibit_sleep_systemd(): Inhibiting systemd sleep: handle-power-key:handle-suspend-key:handle-hibernate-key:handle-lid-switch

(xfce4-power-manager:2770): GLib-CRITICAL **: 18:58:39.598: g_error_free: assertion 'error != NULL' failed

(xfce4-power-manager:2770): xfce4-power-manager-WARNING **: 18:58:39.601: Failed to get keyboard max brightness level : GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: L'interface « org.freedesktop.UPower.KbdBacklight » n'existe pas pour l'objet à l'emplacement /org/freedesktop/UPower/KbdBacklight
(xfce4-power-manager:2770): xfce4-power-manager-WARNING **: 18:58:39.601: Failed to get keyboard max brightness level : GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: L'interface « org.freedesktop.UPower.KbdBacklight » n'existe pas pour l'objet à l'emplacement /org/freedesktop/UPower/KbdBacklight
TRACE[xfpm-polkit.c:244] xfpm_polkit_free_data(): Destroying Polkit data
```

What I found so far :

- If I kill `xfce_power_manager` the same behaviour happens with `xset dpms force off` or its variation force suspend or force standby
- It doesn't matter if jack is running.
- It's stock Ubuntu studio, no other screensaver installed

Here is some config output :

```
$ xfconf-query -c xfce4-power-manager -lv
/xfce4-power-manager/blank-on-ac                    7
/xfce4-power-manager/blank-on-battery               10
/xfce4-power-manager/dpms-enabled                   true
/xfce4-power-manager/dpms-on-ac-off                 9
/xfce4-power-manager/dpms-on-ac-sleep               8
/xfce4-power-manager/dpms-on-battery-off            30
/xfce4-power-manager/dpms-on-battery-sleep          15
/xfce4-power-manager/general-notification           false
/xfce4-power-manager/lock-screen-suspend-hibernate  false
/xfce4-power-manager/logind-handle-lid-switch       false
/xfce4-power-manager/power-button-action            3
/xfce4-power-manager/presentation-mode              false
/xfce4-power-manager/show-panel-label               0
```

```
xset q
Keyboard Control:
  auto repeat:  on    key click percent:  0    LED mask:  00000002
  XKB indicators:
    00: Caps Lock:   off    01: Num Lock:    on     02: Scroll Lock: off
    03: Compose:     off    04: Kana:        off    05: Sleep:       off
    06: Suspend:     off    07: Mute:        off    08: Misc:        off
    09: Mail:        off    10: Charging:    off    11: Shift Lock:  off
    12: Group 2:     off    13: Mouse Keys:  off
  auto repeat delay:  500    repeat rate:  20
  auto repeating keys:  00ffffffdffffbbf
                        fadfffefffedffff
                        9fffffffffffffff
                        fff7ffffffffffff
  bell percent:  50    bell pitch:  400    bell duration:  100
Pointer Control:
  acceleration:  2/1    threshold:  4
Screen Saver:
  prefer blanking:  yes    allow exposures:  yes
  timeout:  420    cycle:  0
Colors:
  default colormap:  0x20    BlackPixel:  0x0    WhitePixel:  0xffffff
Font Path:
  /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,built-ins
DPMS (Energy Star):
  Standby: 480    Suspend: 0    Off: 540
  DPMS is Enabled
  Monitor is On
```

I have a dual monitor configuration in chained DisplayPort to a Nvidia GTX 1660 with driver version 430.50

I'll add further information if needed.

Answer (score -1):

Having crashed my jackd configuration, I did a fresh install of Ubuntu Studio 20.04 and it works, the display are turning off when expected.
Sorry if someone else is having the same issue, I can't offer an easy fix.